# Mysterious "X" in network terminology

Tags: terminology

Many times I've come across that there is an *"X"* added to the end of network-related names on equipment, like how copper cables have wires in them called *TX* and *RX*, and ports on switches can have names like *"100BASE-FX"*. **Why is the X there? Does it mean anything?**

Comment: I thought [we already resolved this question for Rx and Tx](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6610/full-duplex-collisions-in-wires#comment10644_6614)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 8):

[Source: Ethernet_Nomenclature_GA-TB-357.pdf](http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/technical_briefs/Ethernet_Nomenclature_GA-TB-357.pdf)

100BASE-FX

> Optical link that uses short wavelength (850 nm) lasers over two FDDI
>   grade multimode optical Fibers, with eXternal sourced coding. Supports
>   up to at least 2 km.

So, F=fiber, X=external sourced coding

Comment: Allright, but what does "external sourced coding" mean :P?

Comment: Did you try searching for this term in the pdf I linked? Page 5, under "Fast Ethernet (100Mbps)"